# Install4J code signing on windows

Tags: windows, install4j

I'm super curious how install4j is able to do code signing cross platform. It's working really great for me, but I'd just love to know what your approach is for signing windows executables from other OSes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found your extremely detailed page on this at:

http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/04/signing-launchers-and-installers.html

Short answer: use signtool with mono or osslsigncode!

Thanks guys.

Comment: These tools were only used before install4j 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Since install4j 5.1, code signing for Windows and Mac OS X is implemented in Java code and does not require any external tools. Code signing uses open standards both on Windows and Mac OS X, so it's possible to implement it with a crypto library like [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). It's not straight-forward and the details are fairly involved, but no proprietary APIs from the operating system are required.